# Как включить поддержку c++ в JAR библиотеку?

Tags: android

Опыта в сборке библиотеки у меня нет, вот пробую сделать. Нашел статью

https://dominoc925.blogspot.com/2015/09/how-to-create-and-use-jar-archive-using.html

все получается и все работает. Я могу собрать `lib` и потом добавить ее в другой проект `add as a lib` тут вопросов нет. Но теперь мне нужно добавить `native` код в нее. И вопрос как это сделать?

В обычном проекте, нужно добавить скрипт для `CMake`, сами `source` файлы сложить в `cpp` директорию и в `gradle` добавить

```
android {

...

externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }

}
```

Так вот проблема с `gradle` так как когда создаешь библиотеку то в ее `gradle` файле нет блока `android`

Вот все, что там есть

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

sourceCompatibility = "7"
targetCompatibility = "7"
```

Я не уверен, что в `gradle` библиотеки нужно добавлять блок `android`

Так вот вопрос, как это правильно сделать?

Comment: Если библиотека чисто для  Андроида, а не для любой java вообще: `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` и дальше всё почти так же как и в обычном Андроид-проекте. Не могу, правда, сказать во что её потом собирают только `.aar` или `.jar` тоже можно - я их использовал только как модули в том же проекте.

Comment: Раньше делалось это через `jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']` в разделе `android/sourceSets` - если ничего не поменялось конечно

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](https://github.com/ivanovpv/darksms) - проект 5-ти летней давности - там видно как включать `native` исходники и либы в проект

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо @woesss, то что было написано в комментарии мне подошло

> Если библиотека чисто для Андроида, а не для любой java вообще: apply plugin: 'com.android.library' и дальше всё почти так же как и в обычном Андроид-проекте.

То есть `File->New Module->Android Library`, будет сгенерирован модуль который по структуре как обычный проект, только без UI. Я добавил туда конфигурацию для C++ (CMake скрипт и пара строк в `gradle` этого же модуля) и все заработало.

Когда компилируете прокт то `arr` файл можно достать как написано тут

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24316467/5709159

ну а включить созданую либу в другой проект можно вот так

```
File -> NewModule -> Include .JAR/.AAR 

next

File -> ProjectStructure -> Dependencies -> Click on your app module -> + button -> check your just created module as dependency for your app
```

That is it